# How to array_chunk based on array value wildcard?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in PHP returned from database which are user available times for baby sitting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 08:30 - 09:00
    [1] => 09:00 - 09:30
    [2] => 09:30 - 10:00
    [3] => 10:00 - 10:30
    [4] => 10:30 - 11:00
    [5] => 11:00 - 11:30
    [6] => 11:30 - 12:00
    [7] => 12:00 - 12:30
    [8] => 12:30 - 13:00
    [9] => 13:00 - 13:30
    [10] => 13:30 - 14:00
    [11] => 14:00 - 14:30
    [12] => 14:30 - 15:00
    [13] => 15:00 - 15:30
    [14] => 15:30 - 16:00
    [15] => 16:00 - 16:30
    [16] => 16:30 - 17:00
)
```

What I would like to do is show them in 4 different columns:

Night | Morning | Day | Evening

Night should start from 00:00, Morning should start with 06:00, Day should start from  12:00 and Evening from 17:00.

I have to also keep in mind that all users might not have night times available!

How can I split them into four columns?

EDIT:

So I tried to compare the hours in foreach loop, but still am stuck. Any starting points?

```
  foreach ($filtered_times as $key => $value) {
    $startingTimes = substr($value,0,5);

    $startingTimesArray[] = explode(' ', $startingTimes);

    if (date("H") < $startingTimes) {
    } else if (date('H') > $startingTimes && date("H") < 18) {

    } else if(date('H') > 17) {

    }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe split by '-' and then use one of the many date/time functions within PHP to compare? Have you tried anything? This question is too broad for Stack overflow.

Comment: @WillParky93 I tried Jqeury solution since I am returning json but I would like to do it before in the backend. But I havent tried anything on the PHP side

Comment: You could write a function like `getDayTime($timeRange : string) : string`. This function checks using `preg_match` & RegEx what day time we have. You then iterate through the result set and call `getDayTime` and store the time in a new multidimensional array.

Comment: Have a go at it yourself and then come back if you have an issue.Use a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate the array. Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split up the times